# центрировать окно

Tags: visual-basic, vb6

написал часы в заголовке
хочу отцентрировать окно

```
Private OldCaption As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
   frmMain.Caption = "Приложение часы"
   OldCaption = Me.Caption
   frmMain.StartUpPosition = CenterScreen
End Sub

Private Sub tmrTime_Timer()
Dim msg As String
   msg = OldCaption & " : " & Time$
   If msg <> Caption Then
      Caption = msg
   End If
End Sub
```

ругается на StartUpPosition
в чём может быть проблема?

пытался найти решение проблемы в интернете
но проблема так и осталась

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
Me.Left = (Screen.Width - Me.Width) / 2
Me.Top = (Screen.Height - Me.Height) / 2
```

Comment: собственно у меня так и сделано. думал можно с одной команды всё уладить